# What is a <? super List<Object>>? and how can I fix my Observer?

Tags: java, android, database, android-room, observer-pattern

I am trying to build an observer to access data from my Room Database. When I call

```
expenseViewModel.getAllExpenses().observe(this, expenseObserver);
```

my observer expenseObserver won't compile and shows me this error:

```
Required type:
Observer
<? super List<Expense>>
Provided:
Observer
<LiveData<List<Expense>>>
```

For reference this is my entire code for my observer:

```
Observer<LiveData<List<Expense>>> expenseObserver = expenseList -> {
             List<Expense> list = expenseList.getValue();
             expenses.setText(list.get(list.size() - 1).getExpense());
         };

        expenseViewModel.getAllExpenses().observe(this, expenseObserver);
```

Comment: I think it should be `Observer<List<Expense>>`, as you are probably observing a `LiveData` & not a `List` of `LiveData`s.

Comment: Thank you that was exactly it. Now I just need to figure out why my expensesList is empty.